# server and client exits the program

Tags: c, sockets, security, ssl, openssl

When i run server program it executes and will be listening for the connections, the moment i execute client program both client and server will exit the program.
I don't know why it is happening I am running server as `sudo ./server 9000` and my client as `sudo ./client nandan 9000`. Can some one help me whats wrong with this program and thanks in advance.

server program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>
#define FAIL    -1
/*--- OpenListener - create server socket---*/

int OpenListener(int port)
{   
  int sd;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
  {
     perror("can't bind port");
     abort();
  }
  if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )
  {
    perror("Can't configure listening port");
    abort();
  }
  return sd;
  }

/*--- InitServerCTX - initialize SSL server  and create context     ---*/
SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{   
  SSL_library_init();
  SSL_METHOD *method;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;

  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();     /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
  SSL_load_error_strings();         /* load all error messages */
  method = SSLv23_server_method();      /* create new server-method instance */
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);            /* create new context from method */
  if ( ctx == NULL )
  {
     ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
     abort();
  }
  return ctx;
}

/*--- LoadCertificates - load from files---*/

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
/* set the local certificate from CertFile */
  if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "/etc/apache2/ssl/myfirst.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
  {
     ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
     abort();
  }
/* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
  if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
  {
     ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
     abort();
  }
/* verify private key */
  if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
     abort();
  }
}

/*--- ShowCerts - print out certificates.                           ---*/

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{  
  X509 *cert;
  char *line;

  cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* Get certificates (if available) */
  if ( cert != NULL )
  {
     printf("Server certificates:\n");
     line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
     printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
     free(line);
     line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
     printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
     free(line);
     X509_free(cert);
  }
  else
     printf("No certificates.\n");
}
/*--- Servlet - SSL servlet (contexts can be shared) ---*/

void Servlet(SSL* ssl)  /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{  
  char buf[1024];
  char reply[1024];
  int sd, bytes;
  const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

  if ( SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL )                    /* do SSL-protocol accept */
     ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  else
  {
     ShowCerts(ssl);                                /* get any certificates */
     bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));   /* get request */
      if ( bytes > 0 )
      {
         buf[bytes] = 0;
         printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
         sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);         /* construct reply */
         SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply));  /* send reply */
      }
      else
         ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
   }
   sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);                            /* get socket connection */
   SSL_free(ssl);                                   /* release SSL state */
   close(sd);                                       /* close connection */
}

/*--- main - create SSL socket server---*/

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{  
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  int server , c;
  char *portnum;

  if ( count != 2 )
  {
     printf("Usage: %s <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
     exit(0);
  }
  portnum = strings[1];
  printf("%s" , portnum);
  ctx = InitServerCTX();                                /* initialize SSL */
  LoadCertificates(ctx, "newreq.pem", "newreq.pem");    /* load certs */
  server = OpenListener(atoi(portnum));             /* create server socket */
  while (1)
  {   
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    SSL *ssl;
    int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t*)&c);
    printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);             /* get new SSL state with context */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);    /* set connection socket to SSL state */
    Servlet(ssl);               /* service connection */
  }
  close(server);                    /* close server socket */
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
}
```

My client program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define FAIL    -1

/*--- OpenConnection - create socket and connect to server---*/

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{  
  int sd;
  struct hostent *host;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
  {
     perror(hostname);
     abort();
  }
  sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
  if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
  {
     close(sd);
     perror(hostname);
     abort();
  }
  return sd;
}

/*--- InitCTX - initialize the SSL engine---*/

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   
  SSL_library_init();
  SSL_METHOD *method;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;

  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();     /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
  SSL_load_error_strings();         /* Bring in and register error messages */
  method = SSLv23_client_method();      /* Create new client-method instance */
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);        /* Create new context */
  if ( ctx == NULL )
  {
     ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
     abort();
  }
  return ctx;
}

/*--- ShowCerts - print out the certificates---*/

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{    
  X509 *cert;
  char *line;

  cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
  if ( cert != NULL )
  {
    printf("Server certificates:\n");
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    free(line);             /* free the malloc'ed string */
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
    free(line);         /* free the malloc'ed string */
    X509_free(cert);        /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
  }
  else
     printf("No certificates.\n");
}

/*--- main - create SSL context and connect---*/

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{  

  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  int server;
  SSL *ssl;
  char buf[1024];
  int bytes;
  char *hostname, *portnum;

  if ( count != 3 )
  {
     printf("usage: %s <hostname> <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
     exit(0);
  }
 hostname=strings[1];
 portnum=strings[2];

  ctx = InitCTX();
  server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
  ssl = SSL_new(ctx);       /* create new SSL connection state */
  SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);      /* attach the socket descriptor */
  if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */
     ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  else
  {   
    char *msg = "Hello???";
    printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
    ShowCerts(ssl);             /* get any certs */
    SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));   /* encrypt & send message */
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));/* get reply & decrypt */
    buf[bytes] = 0;
    printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
    SSL_free(ssl);          /* release connection state */
  }
  close(server);        /* close socket */
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);      /* release context */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server and client both programs try to `bind()` to same port `9000`. It will fail for client and it will `abort()`.

Not sure why server also exists though.

Your apis/logic in client to connect to server is not correct. You need to create socket and `connect()` to server not  `bind() - listen() - accept()` in client.

Comment: usually they connect to the same port right and  apis/logic in client to connect to server is not correct. What does that mean?